# how to locate model,view and controller when placed inside folder with the same name?

Tags: codeigniter

file finding problem as model, view and controller folders are in different folders of same name in codeigniter.
It shows object not found error

Comment: Please explain more what do you mean with "when placed inside folder with the same name".

Comment: model,views and controllers are to be placed inside folder with same name-admin

Comment: For guiding you in better way kindly provide with folder structure you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put anything in folders. It's a good practice (but not mandatory) to place the views related to a controller in a folder with the same name.
The following would be a correct file structure:

```
/application
    /controllers
        - statistics.php
    /models
        - statistics_model.php
    /views
        /statistics
            - view.php
            - scripts.php
```

Then, in your statistics controller, the code could look like this:

```
class Statistics extends CI_Controller {

private function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {

    $this->load->model('statistics_model');

    $this->load->view('statistics/view');     // html
    $this->load->view('statistics/scripts');  // javascript
}
}
```

Comment: folder structure: admin(folder) inside controllers,admin(folder) inside models,admin(folder) inside views..................And everything is done inside the admin folder...... @ Zeeshan

Comment: That's not the way CodeIgniter works. If you want this behaviour, you will need to hack the core of the framework. The real question is **why** would you do that.